# Im Trying To Automate Buying Something on Amazon With Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Im Trying To Buy A Laptop Automatically But When I Try To Put In The Credit Card Number It Gives The Error `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate` Im Using Xpath btw.

Comment: Please, post the whole web element HTML code that you are trying to automate. in advance, using Xpath is the last option when webscrapping. element IDs are prefeered in most cases, specially in big stable sites such amazon.

Comment: Im Still kind Of Learning So Might I Ask How Do I Post The HTML Code?

Comment: In chrome, press F12, then ctrl+shift+C to enable the element selector, click on the field that you are trying to automate. It will show you the piece of HTML code that you are trying to select. Then copy here.

Comment: <input type="tel" id="pp-1DUIVO-14" autocomplete="off" name="addCreditCardNumber" class="a-input-text a-form-normal"> Thats The Code I Think. (Sorry For The Late Response)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if your element is

```
<input type="tel" id="pp-1DUIVO-14" autocomplete="off" name="addCreditCardNumber" class="a-input-text a-form-normal">
```

you can click on it using

```
my_input = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[id="pp-1DUIVO-14"]')
my_input .click()
```

Comment: or just `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[id="pp-1DUIVO-14"]').click` would work

Answer (score 0):

If u try to locate it by id. It is false. I'd will be keep changing for everytime. Try to identify with name "addCreditCardaNumber"
It will work for u.